# jquery click function on a d3.js node

Tags: php, jquery, d3.js

I want to use jQuery to handle a mouse click on nodes in a force directed network graph.  That way, I can run AJAX calls to a PHP page that extracts data about that node via a mySQL query.

But I am struggling how to integrate d3.js with jQuery.  I tried this (see jQuery after //click event), but not surprisingly it does not work because 'node' is clearly not the correct ID.  When I use HTML div tags, its easy, but with d3.js I am not sure the equivalent ID to use.

Thanks, Tom

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    //click event

$("node").click(function(){
  alert("The node was clicked.");
});



    //Set margins and sizes
    var margin = {
        top: 20,
        bottom: 50,
        right: 30,
        left: 50
    };
    var width = 1920 - margin.left - margin.right;
    var height = 1080 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    //Load Color Scale
    var c10 = d3.scale.category10();
    //Create an SVG element and append it to the DOM
    var svgElement = d3.select("body")
                        .append("svg").attr({"width": width+margin.left+margin.right, "height": height+margin.top+margin.bottom})
                        .append("g")
                        .attr("transform","translate("+margin.left+","+margin.top+")"); 
    //Load External Data
    d3.json("php/index_network_methy.php", function(dataset){
        //Extract data from dataset
        var nodes = dataset.nodes,
            links = dataset.links;
        //Create Force Layout
        var force = d3.layout.force()
                        .size([width, height])
                        .nodes(nodes)
                        .links(links)
                        .gravity(0.1)
                        .charge(-200)
                        .linkDistance(100);
        //Add links to SVG
        var link = svgElement.selectAll(".link")
                    .data(links)
                    .enter()
                    .append("line")
                    .attr("stroke-width", function(d){ return d.weight/1; })
                    .attr("class", "link");
        //Add nodes to SVG
        var node = svgElement.selectAll(".node")
                    .data(nodes)
                    .enter()
                    .append("g")
                    .attr("class", "node")
                    .call(force.drag);
        //Add labels to each node
        var label = node.append("text")
                        .attr("dx", 24)
                        .attr("dy", "0.35em")
                        .attr("font-size", function(d){ return d.influence*1.5>9? d.influence*1.5: 9; })
                        .text(function(d){ return d.character; });
        //Add circles to each node
        var circle = node.append("circle")
                        .attr("r", function(d){ return d.influence/2>15 ? d.influence/2 : 15; })
                        .attr("fill", function(d){ return c10(d.zone*10); });
        //This function will be executed for every tick of force layout 
        force.on("tick", function(){
            //Set X and Y of node
            node.attr("r", function(d){ return d.influence; })
                .attr("cx", function(d){ return d.x; })
                .attr("cy", function(d){ return d.y; });
            //Set X, Y of link
            link.attr("x1", function(d){ return d.source.x; })
            link.attr("y1", function(d){ return d.source.y; })
            link.attr("x2", function(d){ return d.target.x; })
            link.attr("y2", function(d){ return d.target.y; });
            //Shift node a little
            node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
        });
        //Start the force layout calculation
        force.start();
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your listener declaration `$("node").click` does not reference any element

`node` is not an element.

You have elements with class `node` so your jquery declaration should perhaps be

```
$('.node').click... //  (note the dot)
```

If that doesn't work, it's likely because you're attaching the listener before the elements are in the dom.

A good approach for d3 is to add the a regular javascript listener when you append the node.  See [d3 handling events](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#handling-events)

Comment: Thanks!  It appears you are correct on both counts - adding the dot before 'node' and moving the click event after force.start.